# Check if a __slots__ variable has been assigned

Tags: python, python-3.x, slots

Suppose an object exists that is an instance of a class with a **slots** list defined, and not all variables are assigned in **init**. Rather, they are assigned at some time in the future. Is there a way to check if one of those initially unassigned, **slots** allocated variables has been assigned yet?

Thanks!

-PolyyloP

Comment: https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/__slots__magic.html and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472000/usage-of-slots wiki https://wiki.python.org/moin/UsingSlots

Comment: I'd like to see a good reason to leave the attributes undefined after `__init__` exits.

Comment: Use `hasattr` or simply access the attribute in a `try` ... `except AttributeError`